# Derivative of series in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

I have an equation like:

```
y= Sum[ i x[i] , {i,10}]
```

and I want to calculate the derivative :

```
D[y,x[i]] -> = i
```

How can I do that in mathematica ?

I can do `D[y, x[3]]` and it gives me 3 
but if I enter `D[y, x[i]]` it returns 0 but I expect i.

Is there a way to define the parametric derivative for series like the above in Mathematica ?

Comment: sugest you fix your notation .. y = Sum[i x[i], {i, 10}] ; D[y,x[3]]-> 3 ; D[y,x[i]] -> 0

Comment: The correct reult is not "i", but rather "i if i is an integer in range 1:10 and zero otherwise."  That should give a clue why this isn't a trivial thing to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way to think about your problem, anyway :

Build the list of your variables :

```
vars = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 10}]
(* {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10} *)
```

Build your function :

```
expr = Dot[Range[10], vars]
(* x1 + 10 x10 + 2 x2 + 3 x3 + 4 x4 + 5 x5 + 6 x6 + 7 x7 + 8 x8 + 9 x9 *)
```

Take the derivatives :

```
D[expr, #] & /@ vars 
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few things to consider.

1. The notation `x_3` does not mean x with index 3. It means three times x_.
   You should use Subscript[x,3] instead.
2. Your y is:  `Sum[n * Subscript[x, n], {n, 1, 5}]`
3. You can now find the partial deriviative:
     `D[Sum[n * Subscript[x, n], {n, 1, 5}], Subscript[x, 2]]`
   gives 2.
4. `D[Sum[Subscript[x, n], {n, 1, 5}], Subscript[x, j]]` gives 0.
   The reason is that `Subscript[x, j]` is considered a variable.